# What is the difference between providers and imports in nestjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Im following the nestJs [authentication tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication)

In  auth/auth.module.ts:

```
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt'


...

@Module({
  imports: [

    UsersModule,
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
```

So JwtModule is imported under 'imports' .

In the auth/auth.service.ts the JwtService is being injected

```
...
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private jwtService: JwtService
  ) {}

...
```

From the nestJs docs:

Under Module:
providers   - the providers that will be instantiated by the Nest injector and that may be shared at least across this module

```
imports -   the list of imported modules that export the providers which are required in this module
```

Under Providers:

```
Providers are a fundamental concept in Nest.
Many of the basic Nest classes may be treated as a provider – services, repositories, 
factories, helpers, and so on. 
The main idea of a provider is that it can be injected as a dependency; 
this means objects can create various relationships with each other, and the function 
of "wiring up" instances of objects can largely be delegated to the Nest runtime system
```

I don't really understand . Whats the difference between providers and imports if both are used for dependency injection ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Think of a provider as a single thing that can be injected and used. It can be a full class, like an `AuthService`, or an object like `{ secretOrKey: 'sup3rs3cr3t' }` or even just a number like `42`. Each of these objects would be represented by a provider token: for classes, this is just the class reference itself which will later be read via the emitted metadata, the object and number would be represented by an injection token specified by a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) like

```js
{
  provide: 'JWT_OPTIONS',
  useValue: {
    secretOrKey: 'sup3rs3cr3t',
  }
}
```

or

```js
{
  provide: 'THE_ANSWER',
  useValue: 42,
}
```

To inject these custom providers, by the way, you'd end up using `@Inject('JWT_OPTIONS')` or `@Inject('THE_ANSWER')` in the constructor of another service or just the injection tokens in an `inject` array for a [factory custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory)

---

Modules, on the other hand, are a collection of modules, providers, controllers, and exports, that tie a feature together. Almost think of it like a container, it has its own private API (providers that aren't exports) (these are providers and methods that are used from within the module but not outside of it), a public API (exported providers) (these are providers and imported modules that are used both inside and outside of the module) and external entry points (controllers, resolvers, gateways) (these are ways that transports can talk to your application and specifically your module).

What a module declares under its `providers` array, Nest will create that provider in the context of the module: this goes for providers that are instantiated in other modules, providers that are just objects, etc, they'll be created with whatever resources the module has.

Most of the time, if you declare a provider in two providers arrays you're going to have side effects that you don't expect to have. What you usually want to do instead is to have a single module declare the provider and add it to its `exports` array, then in another module import the first to get access to those `exports`; this will have Nest re-use the existing provider in the new module to allow usage of the provider without needing to recreate it.

---

On to your example of the `JwtModule`, if we [take a look at the source module](https://github.com/nestjs/jwt/blob/master/lib/jwt.module.ts) we'll see that there is one provider that is always present, the `JwtService`, and it is also always exported, and there is one provider that shows up when you use `register/registerAsync`, the `JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS` provider. This provider is **never** exported, so it's only existing inside of the module. However, when we import the `JwtModule`, whatever module we import the `JwtModule` into now can inject the `JwtService` into its `providers` due to the `JwtModule` having the `JwtService` in the `exports`. If a provider were to try to inject `JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS`, then there would be an error, as the new module doesn't know about that provider (unless of course you make your own provider for it with the same name)

Hopefully this all helps clear things up

Comment: What are the possible side effects that can be caused by declaring the same provider in two providers arrays?

Comment: Loss of state between the two instances of the provider as that's not shared. Depending on how the provider is instantiated, possibly loss of config (like for the `JwtService`), just to name a few